# An apparent counterexample to the duality of openness and closedness

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I'm reading 'Charles Chapman Pugh - Real Mathematical Analysis', and based on the given definitions, it seems to me that the following stated theorem is false.

[image]

Now this is how a metric space is defined:

> A metric space is a set M, the elements of which are referred to as points of M,
> together with a metric d having the three properties that distance has in Euclidean
> space.

Now, the set [-2,2] with the Euclidean distance function is a metric space (let's call it M), right? The set [-1,1] is closed in M, but its complement, which is the union of [-2,-1) and (1,2] is neither open nor closed. Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: It’s open in the [relative topology](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subspace_topology)

Comment: Please don't rely on images to convey information not otherwise present in your post. [See here for an explanation of why this is bad practice.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/742)

Comment: $[-2,-1)\cup(1,2]$ is open in the space $[-2,2]$ with the Euclidean metric.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The set $[-2, -1) \cup (1, 2]$ is an open set in the metric space $M$, which is what is relevant -- you can check the definition.

The set $[-2, -1) \cup (1, 2]$ is *not* an open set in the metric space $\mathbb R$, but there it is also not the complement of the closed set $[-1, 1]$, so that is not a problem.